# Dereferencing a pointer by multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, this, smart-pointers

In the example below, suppose I have a multithreaded queue i.e. supports multiple writes and reads from different threads (e.g. using mutex). We can see that 1. the pointer `this` as well as 2. the shared pointer `m_mulque` are passed to the readers and writers and my question is: Dereferencing the pointers `this` and `m_mulque` is thread safe or not? In other words is my following code thread safe or not meaning should I worry about any undefined behaviour if I run this please?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

struct multithreaded_queue
{
    void push(const std::size_t i) 
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push(i);
    };

    void try_pop() 
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.pop();
    };

private:
    std::queue<std::size_t> m_queue;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

```
class example
{
public:
    example()
    {
        m_mulque = std::make_shared<multithreaded_queue>();
    };

    void run()
    {
        auto writer = [this]()
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                m_mulque->push(i);
            };
        };

        auto reader = [this]()
        {
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                m_mulque->try_pop();
            };
        };

        std::thread writer1(writer);
        std::thread reader1(reader);
        std::thread reader2(reader);

        writer1.join();
        reader1.join();
        reader2.join();
    };

private:
    std::shared_ptr<multithreaded_queue> m_mulque;
};
```

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    example ex;
    ex.run(); //Is this thread safe to call?
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason you think this should not be thread-safe?

Comment: Since you never change *this* and never change *m_mulque*, I'd say it's fine, given that *multithreaded_queue* is implemented properly.

Comment: @user253751 I agree with you just wanted to be sure. I didn't find the cpp reference that derefencing is thread safe. I found that the counter is.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Thanks very much that answers my question.

Comment: it could only be thread-unsafe if something changed

Comment: of course you don't mean the object multithreaded_queue but the pointers. push and pop are not implemented in my example but they are actually pushing and poping in my real use case :)

Comment: Dereferencing is neither thread-safe nor thread-unsafe.  Dereferencing to **read** is thread-safe.  Dereferencing to **write** may not be safe.

Comment: If the state of `multithreaded_queue` object changes on 1 thread and is read or changed on a 2nd thread you have a data-race.  But as the implementation of `multithreaded_queue` has been omitted we can't be sure.

Comment: So sorry I know you are saying specific phrases and I think it's my fault I should have implemented the multithreaded_queue. But please I am confused, dereferencing for write is ok i this case no? The multithreaded_queue supports data race we agree?

Comment: `m_mulque` is created before both threads start.  Starting a `std::thread` is a synchronisation point.  Reading `m_mulque` (dereferencing it) from multiple threads is always safe.  It's only a potential problem when the code has at least 1 writer and another reader/writer

Comment: OK I see, you are refering to the pointers. All pointers are created before starting to run and the pointers themselves are unchanged. I add a non-optimized version with a non needed mutable in the example

Comment: Thanks. In my code I never write in the shared pointer but only in the safe object i.e. the queue so I am good